# Changing font-size with jQuery css() function is crashing Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, font-size

So I have this bit of code that works perfectly in FF and IE8, but it's crashing Chrome:

```
while($('#movie-info .vote').height()>30) {
    $size = $('#movie-info .vote').css('font-size').replace('px','');
    $('#movie-info .vote').css('font-size',($size-0.5)+'px');
}
```

Comment: idk why this is but it works with `-1`

Comment: Define "manages to chrash[sic] Chrome"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that happens because chrome doesn't allow font-size to go under a certain limit, but when font-size reaches the limit, height is still > 30..?

I think you should avoid the for loop, and instead recalculate optimum font size at once, depending on `'#movie-info .vote'` height..

### UPDATE

To have one-line rows, with hidden continuation, use something like this:

```
#movie-info .vote {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Try this out here: http://jsfiddle.net/fvcHd/4/

Comment: By the way, what do you exactly want to accomplish? Give `.vote` the same font-size to make all of them `<= 30px` in height?

Comment: im trying to make the content fit the container in one row so the container doesnt stretch out.
   
the default font-size is 16px and this seem to work.. dont get why the while loop doesnt.
 
   if($('#movie-info #info').height()>30) {
        $('#movie-info #info').css('font-size','13px');
    }

Comment: @ulph I guess the thing is: you try to set small font-size, but chrome doesn't allow you, so the height never goes under 30px and the loop never ends.. If you want to limit height to one row, you'd better do that using CSS

Comment: thanks for you suggestions.. but somehow my code works with -1 instead of -0.5.

Comment: Ok, so maybe the problem here is that chrome is rounding font-size to an integer value; anyways, doing this kind of things with CSS instead of JavaScript is way much better/failsafe/resources saving..

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this old question looking for a different issue, but I think I can shed some light on the issue, especially considering the "works with -1 instead of -0.5" thing.

Chrome and other WebKit-based browsers handle unit rounding differently than Firefox and IE. While Firefox does its best to render and report fractional pixel sizes and IE renders rounded sizes but continues to report exactly what you specified, WebKit rounds the rendered value AND reports the rounded value when you ask for it back.

Let's say the size starts at 14px. When you run this code:

```
// $size = 14
$size = $('#movie-info .vote').css('font-size').replace('px','');
// font-size: 13.5px
$('#movie-info .vote').css('font-size',($size-0.5)+'px');
```

Chrome rounds off your size change and the font size is still 14px. So, the loop will never stop because `$size` never decreases.

A simple solution would be to declare $size once instead of asking Chrome what it is:

```
// Don't forget to declare with `var` to give $size local scope!
// Otherwise it is declared in global scope which could lead to
// weird bugs or lost performance.
var $size = $('#movie-info .vote').css('font-size').replace('px','');
while ($('#movie-info .vote').height() > 30) {
    $size = $size - 0.5;
    $('#movie-info .vote').css('font-size', $size + 'px');
}
```